# C++ Visual Studio Error Stack around variable " " is corrupted

Tags: c++, visual-studio

So, I am having trouble with my program. It is suppose to sort an array when values are inputed from the user. THe program runs fine, however, I am getting an error that I cant figure out where its from. I tried f5 and breaking but it doesn't tell me anything.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
// ConsoleApplication3.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
// 
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"


using namespace std;
#define Array_Size 15

int main()
{
    int num[Array_Size] = { 10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100 };
    int count = 0;
    int input,prev_num_1, prev_num_2,sizeTofill;
    int f;
    bool checkLoop;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter a number" << endl;
        cin >> input;
        checkLoop = true;
        f = 0; // if the third input(when i =2) is larger than the rest, we need f to =0 before it enters the loop
        for (int j = 0; j < Array_Size; j++)
        {
            if (input <= num[j]&&(checkLoop==true))
            {
                checkLoop = false;
                sizeTofill = Array_Size - j;
                prev_num_1 = num[j];
                num[j] = input;

                for (f = j; f < sizeTofill; f++)
                {

                    prev_num_2 = num[f + 1];
                    num[f + 1] = prev_num_1;
                    prev_num_1 = prev_num_2;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        if (f==0)
        {
            num[10 + i] = input;
        }
    }

    for (int z = 0; z < Array_Size; z++)
    {
        cout << num[z] << endl;
        count++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This usually means you are going out of bounds with your array indexes. If j=0 it looks like you can access `num[Array_Size +1]` with `num[f + 1]`

Comment: ***THe program runs fine*** The error means you have UB.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I found the error. Thank you!